# internode communication issue

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

We have noticed in one of prod cluster that one of node was trying to communicte or Handshake with other cluster nodes in same AWS Account/Network zone. I'm not sure why it is happening. I have verified the configuration and looks good with respective node IP address. Did anyone experience this behaviour?

DB Version: 4.0.1

Regards,
Mani

Comment: It sounds like your snitch properties are wrong. Did you check the cassandra-rackdc.properties or cassandra-topology.properties files?

Comment: @stevenlacerda The configuration looks good. The new node was used by other cluster few months back and the same IP address has been assgined to different cluster node now.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the seed list configured on both clusters as well as using cqlsh to check system.peers on both clusters.

Normally if a node attempts to communicate with a cluster it is a not a part of, the log will contain a warning. It knows it's not a part of the cluster due to the cluster name not matching.

I've see then in clusters where the seed list on 1 cluster, was using names and the DNS had an incorrect address.